# F#: Problems when returning List of lists via pattern matching?

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

So I have this code that will basically split a list by k items.
So if there's the list [1;2;3;4;5;6;7] and I want to split the first k = 3 items away, then it'll split the list into [1;2;3] and [4;5;6;7].

I want to return both of these, so my plan is to put them into a list of lists, OR it would be even better to put them into a tuple of 2 lists. 
So I'm returning [[1;2;3]; [4;5;6;7]] or ([1;2;3], [4;5;6;7]).

I also tried doing this by turning the two lists into tuples, but I couldn't figure out how to return the empty tuples of lists for the last pattern match.

Also, I know that this can be done simpler with some kind of .take or .split function but I'm trying to understand F# so I'm doing it this way.

But please help!
My error is: 
Expecting a
     ''a'
 but given a
     ''a list'

```
let populateList k =
  let data = [1;2;3;4;5;6;7]
  let rec helper count aList =
    match aList with
    | head::tail when count < k ->
        let theTail = tail
        let newList = head :: helper (count+1) tail
        //let aTuple = (theTail,newList)
        //aTuple
        [theTail; newList]
    | _ -> []
    helper 0 data

 populateList 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The helper function must track both the result lists to work in a recursive construct. Here is an example:

```
let populateList k =
  let data = [1;2;3;4;5;6;7]
  let rec helper count (first_k, rest) =
    if count < k then
        match rest with
        | a::tail -> helper (count+1) (a::first_k, tail)
        | _ -> ([],[])
    else (first_k |> List.rev, rest)
  helper 0 ([], data)

populateList 3
```